# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite, zlib

Using SQLite3 in Python, I am trying to store a compressed version of a snippet of UTF-8 HTML code.

Code looks like this:

```
...
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute('create table blah (cid integer primary key,html blob)')
...
c.execute('insert or ignore into blah values (?, ?)',(cid, zlib.compress(html)))
```

At which point at get the error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

If I use 'text' rather than 'blob' and don't compress the HTML snippet, it works all fine (db is to large though). When I use 'blob' and compress via Python zlib library, I get the above error message. I looked around but couldn't find a simple answer for this one.

Answer (score 96):

If you want to use 8-bit strings instead of unicode string in sqlite3, set appropriate text_factory for sqlite connection:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(...)
connection.text_factory = str
```

Comment: This may give you problems with different encodings, since you're still trying to parse binary data as text. It's best to use sqlite3.Binary instead.

Answer (score 35):

Found the solution, I should have spent just a little more time searching.

Solution is to 'cast' the value as a Python 'buffer', like so:

```
c.execute('insert or ignore into blah values (?, ?)',(cid, buffer(zlib.compress(html))))
```

Hopefully this will help somebody else.

Comment: When I did this, my database was full of base36 text, which would make the database larger than storing the blob directly.

Comment: This is incorrect, you should use sqlite3.Binary instead as the documentation says.

Comment: It looks like sqlite3.Binary() is simply an alias of buffer(), at least as of https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/blob/master/lib/dbapi2.py#L54

Comment: Huh.  And it also looks like this section of the pysqlite docs actually encourage the buffer() usage:  "The following Python types can thus be sent to SQLite without any problem: ... "[Python type] buffer ... [SQLite type] BLOB"  https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#introduction

Answer (score 35):

In order to work with the BLOB type, you must first convert your zlib compressed string into binary data - otherwise sqlite will try to process it as a text string. This is done with sqlite3.Binary(). For example:

```
c.execute('insert or ignore into blah values (?, ?)',(cid, 
sqlite3.Binary(zlib.compress(html))))
```

Comment: this works. However, I was wondering why this is needed. Did the type "BLOB" already indicate the data in this column is binary? Note in Python 2 the string can be either text or binary. Shouldn't sqlite3 just treat the object (zlib compressed string) as binary for BLOB type?

Comment: i don't think Python has the entire database schema in memory to consult the correct data types - most likely it just guesses the types on runtime based on what you pass it, so a binary string can't be differenciated from a text string.

Comment: Because SQLite uses dynamic type: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html @user1783732

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

5 types of possible storage: NULL, INTEGER, TEXT, REAL and BLOB

BLOB is generally used to store pickled models or dill pickled models

```
> cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Tablename(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) VALUES(?,?,?,?)''', 
                                      [TextValue, Real_Value, Buffer(model), sqlite3.Binary(model2)])
> conn.commit()

> # Read Data:
> df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Model, con=conn) 
> model1 = str(df['Col3'].values[0]))
> model2 = str(df['Col'].values[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value using repr(html) instead of the raw output and then use eval(html) when retrieving the value for use.

```
c.execute('insert or ignore into blah values (?, ?)',(1, repr(zlib.compress(html))))
```

Comment: Using eval and repr like this is very dirty. No matter how much you trust a data-source.

Comment: I agree, anything is better than eval() here. The right solution is using sqlite3.Binary, but if you can't for some reason, it's better to encode the data in a safer way - for example with base64.