# python sqlite3 Double quotes resulting query failure

Tags: python, database, django, sqlite

I have a Sqlite3 table
    paste{
       paste_id int,
       paste_content text
    }

i have to do an update statement, where text can possibly contain single ' quotes as well as "" double quotes.
In python i wrote

```
UPDATE_Statement = "Update paste set paste_content = '%s' where paste_id=id" %(content)
```

But since the content can contain ' or "" , my execute query is not working properly.
How can i escape this properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* use string interpolation. Use SQL parameters instead:

```
UPDATE_Statement = "Update paste set paste_content = %s where paste_id=%s"

cursor.execute(UPDATE_Statement, content)
```

and leave escaping (and proper quoting) up to the database adapter instead. This:

- Simplifies your code
- Quotes different data types correctly
- Lets the database reuse query plans for varying data
- Prevents SQL injection attacks

See the [Passing parameters into `raw()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) in the Django SQL documentation.

If you are using a different database connector (not the connection provided by Django) verify the specific style of parameter placeholders in the documentation. The `sqlite3` database adapter for example, uses `?` as the placeholder syntax.

Comment: how can i write when i have more parameters like content1,content 2 ?

Comment: All parameters are positional; use one `%s` per parameter, and pass in the values as a sequence in the second argument (list, tuple, etc.).

Comment: `UPDATE_Statement = "Update paste set paste_content = %s content2= %s where paste_id=%d"

cursor.execute(UPDATE_Statement, (content1,content2,id))`

The above statement gave me error again.

Comment: Django only supports `%s`, not `%d`, for parameters. However, a `SyntaxError` exception usually indicates you did something *else* wrong somewhere, but without a full traceback that is hard to tell exactly what that might be.

Comment: Also, a SQL `UPDATE` statement uses commas between the columns. `UPDATE_Statement = "Update paste set paste_content = %s, content2= %s where paste_id=%d"`

Comment: @user1159517: Right, what database connector? `sqlite3` uses `?` placeholders, not `%s`. So the query would be `UPDATE_Statement = "Update paste set paste_content = ? where paste_id=?"` in that case.

Comment: Database: sqlite3
I tried putting question marks
st = Update tableName set Column1= ?,Colum2=? where colum3=?
cursor.execute(st,(c1,c2,c3)) 
i am getting this error now.
**You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.**

Comment: See [sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text\_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3425320)

Comment: I have added this
con.text_factory = str
Problem Solved ! . Thanks !