# SQLite3 : You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

In order to teach myself python, I have been playing with the whois module, and sqlalchemy

I am writing an app which goes through a list of words, and does a lookup for each words with a .tld added. This is working well, but some of the data returns are making SQLite throw the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings. [SQL: u'INSERT INTO domains (domain, country, city, updated_date, expiration_date, registrar) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'<domain removed>', 'DE', 'Hohenm\xf6lsen', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 17, 0, 0), '<provider removed>')]
```

It seems to be this string:

```
'Hohenm\xf6lsen'
```

In an attempt to fix this, I have used a text factory

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///myDB.db')
engine.connect().connection.text_factory = str
```

I have also tried using utf-8 in my while loop the reads from a dictionary list:

```
with codecs.open(dictfile, 'rb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

I have also check the variable type for all the entries, and they are all strings, and not arrays or blobs.

My full code can be seen here:

https://github.com/tripledown/domainfinder/blob/master/domainfinder.py

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text\_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425320/sqlite3-programmingerror-you-must-not-use-8-bit-bytestrings-unless-you-use-a-te)

Comment: I looked at that, but he is executing natively (c.execute) whereas I am using sqlaclhemy (+ my added noobness)

Answer (score 0):

add this line for assigning text_factory. It converts strings into unicode objects.

```
conn = GetSqliteConnection(db_path) conn.text_factory = lambda x: unicode(x, 'utf-8', 'ignore')
```